# Angular 4: injecting StateService into other services

Tags: angular

I'm used to inject the `StateService` into components in order to transition to other states.

But now I have the need to inject the 'StateService' into other *services* and call those services from my components instead. Basically: 1. I need to set a property internally in the other service that is needed for the other state and 2. I need to transition to this other state. I don't want to pass this property in the query string because of security concerns.

For example, the following method in a cart component internally sets the selected products in the cart service *and* transitions to the check-out state:

```
// cart component:
onClick() {
  this.cartService.transitionToCheckout(this.products);
}
```

I'm wondering how conventional this is in the Angular world. My main concern is that I'm calling a method that seems to do too many things.

Comment: I don't think there's a problem doing something like that

Comment: What exactly is a state service ? Do you mean something like routing ?

Comment: inject in the constructor as if was a component